# Not getting value of input type created through a directive in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am using a directive for datepicker in angularJS. Below is my code for directive. It works well and it shows datepicker when I add datepicker directive in a `div.now` I want to use the selected date in my form when I send data in controller and from controller I pass it to php api via `$http`. when I check the data in php it does not shows date. Rest all fields are working fine only the field created with directive is not showing the values. I am pasting the code for directive, controller and form.

```
app.directive('datepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'datepickerCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'dp',
        template: '<div id="dob" ng-controller="profileCtrl" dob class="input-group date" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy" ><input class="from_to_input"  name="1" type="text" ng-class={inputError:dp.validDate==false} class="form-control input-sm"  ng-model="profile.value"/><span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span></div>',
        scope: {
            'value': '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attribute) {
            //  scope.variable = attribute.value;
        }
    };
});
```

below is code for controller for datepicker

```
  app.controller('datepickerCtrl', function ($scope) {        
    $('.date').datepicker({ autoclose: true, todayHighlight: true });
    var inputDate = new Date(moment($scope.value));
    $scope.value = moment(inputDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
    $('.date').datepicker('setDate', inputDate);

    $scope.$watch('value', function (newVal) {                  
    });
});
```

below is code for my form page

```
<form name="profileForm" role="form">
                    <input type="email" id="" name="email"  ng-model="profile.email" class="login_input_area" placeholder="Email">
                     <div class="col-xs-2" datepicker  value="date2"></div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" ng-click="saveprofile(profile)" class="submit_btn">
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend! 
Please check online video tutorials for Angular directives!

Anyway, in your directive you have ng-model="profile.value", that should be "value" I think

second: remove ng-controller="profileCtrl" from directive template. Directives has they own local scope.

third: I prefer using restrict: "E", so you can use as custom tag, more readable on my opinion

one more: scope: { value : "="} , not scope: { 'value' : "="}

couple more: remove both controller: 'datepickerCtrl', controllerAs: 'dp'

Comment: Not the exact solution but your suggestions helped me to get the solution.thanks